# How come selectSingleNode returns nothing?

Tags: xml, vb.net, attributes

I am trying to select a node by a unique attribute, however I am getting nothing returned to me.
I have checked here: [SelectSingleNode returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517554/selectsinglenode-returns-nothing) and here: [why does Msxml DocumentElement/SelectSingleNode returns nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645044/why-does-msxml-documentelement-selectsinglenode-returns-nothing)

My goal is to be able to update one of the nodes attributes.
My XML Looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings>
    <options>
... other nodes here ...
   </options>
  <selected>
    <pref set_number="1" set_name="Five" name="Number" value="5"/>
    <pref set_number="3" set_name="Nine" name="Number" value="9"/>
  </selected>
</settings>
```

And this is my Sub
(I have commented what I have tried)

```
Sub WriteXMLAttributeValues()
        Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
        Dim fSuccess As Boolean = False
        Dim oRoot As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode = Nothing
        Dim oAtrb As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement = Nothing
        Dim oLst As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList = Nothing

        oDoc.async = False
        oDoc.validateOnParse = False
        fSuccess = oDoc.load("C:\settings.xml")

        'oRoot = oDoc.childNodes("settings").childNodes("selected").attributes("set_number")
            'oRoot = oDoc.selectSingleNode("//settings/selected[@set_number='1' and @value='5']")
            'oRoot = oDoc.selectSingleNode("//settings/selected[@set_number='1']")
            'oAtrb.setAttribute("name", "Twenty")
            'oLst = oDoc.selectSingleNode("/settings/selected[@set_number='1']")
            'oAtrb.setAttribute("name", "Twenty")
            oRoot = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("set_number")
            oDoc.save("C:\settings2.xml")
    End Sub
```

I am trying to change the first **< pref >**'s attribute from **"Five"** to **"Twenty"**

I would like to know what I am doing wrong so I can properly update the attribute.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to access the set_number attribute on the <selected> element, not the <pref> element. Try //settings/selected/pref[...]

Comment: If you are using VB.NET, then you should not be using MSXML. Use LINQ to XML, or at worst XmlDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forgetting the pref element in the path. It should look something like this.

```
Dim node as XmlNode
node = oDoc.selectSingleNode("//settings/selected/pref[@set_number='1']")
```

You can then change the attributes like so:

```
node.Attributes("set_name").Value = "Twenty"
```

Comment: Edited your answer: if he requires more help he should ask a new question. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @Nathan, Thanks I was totally overlooking the /pref element. I was trying to use ***MSXML2**, but I ended up switching to **System.xml** because I couldn't get **MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode.Attributes** to work